# Problems doing a tripwire database update: No protocol specified / QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0 / Interactive Update failed

Tags: debian, integrity, tripwire

So I'm trying to run an update to the tripwire database via `./tripwire --update --twrfile ./report/name.twr` as described [here](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/doc/redhat/redhat8/rhl-rg-en-8.0/s1-tripwire-update-db.html) as root on my computer but I get these errors (note that --init and --check worked fine):

> No protocol specified
>   QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0
>   Aborted
>   Interactive Update failed.
>   Error: Editor could not be launched.

I'm running Debian 9.1 with KDE. How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple you don't have the `DISPLAY=:0` environment variable set.

1. You could run:

   ```
   export DISPLAY=:0; ./tripwire --update --twrfile ./report/name.twr
   ```
2. or you could logout from the terminal root session and start new one without passing - argument that will make you inherit env variables of current session including the `DISPLAY` variable. So press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> and then run `su`. Type your password, then you can check your environment with the `env` command and `grep` for `DISPLAY`:

   ```
   env | grep DISPLAY
   ```
3. you could change your default editor to something that is console based like `nano` or `vim`. You should change as the article mentioned `EDITOR` field in your tripwire configuration file.

   > Tripwire will display the report file using the default text editor specified on the EDITOR line of the Tripwire configuration file

Choose the way you want to do it. Either one of those three ways will allow you to open GUI based application or change the GUI text editor setting into the console based one.

The first one and second one are simplest assuming that you want to use the graphical editor to view the content of the Tripwire reports.

Answer (score 0):

Newer systems by design don't allow graphical applications as root (it's a Wayland thing). Workaround:

```
$ xhost si:localuser:root

$ sudo -i
$ ...your-graphical-app...
```

Restore the default permissions:

```
$ xhost -si:localuser:root
```